# m2Relese plugin 0.14.0 not working with older svn versions

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

I created a relsease job in jenking. I used m2Release pluging 0.14.0. Job was successfuly bulilded. But while "Perform Maven Release" it gives an error as

[ERROR] svnorg: invalid option: --parents

I think problem is with my svn version. SVN version is 1.4.2 and it does not know command "--parents"

So how can I used m2Release plugin with SVN older version like 1.4.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use up-to-date Subversion release. There is no practical reason to keep using SVN 1.4.x client.

Comment: Thanks @bahrep I change the SVN version now it is ok.